# Finding empty line using fscanf

Tags: c, scanf, stdio, ungetc

I'm supposed to read some variables named from "A" to "Z" and then evaluate them. The values in variables are matrices. This is example input:

```
B=[5 2 4; 0 2 -1; 3 -5 -4]
E=[-6 -5 -8; -1 -1 -10; 10 0 -7]
R=[-1 -7 6; -2 9 -4; 6 -10 2]

R+E+B
```

I have written an algorithm that correctly reads all the variables. However I fail at detecting the empty line. I have written this:

```
// FILE* input = stdin; 
while(true) {
    char name = '#';
    // Reads the matrix, returns null on error
    Matrix* A = matrix_read_prp_2(input, &name);
    if( A==NULL ) {
        // throw error or something
    }
    // Print the matrix
    matrix_print_prp_2(A, stdout);
    // consume one new line
    char next;
    if(fscanf(input, "\n%c", &next)!=1)
        // Program returns error here
    if(next=='\n')
        break;
    // if not new line, put the char back
    // and continue
    ungetc(next, input);
}
```

I assumed that for empty line, `fscanf(input, "\n%c", &next)` would read `'\n'` into `next`, but it actually skips the second line and reads `R`.

How can I check if next line is empty on stream in C?

Comment: It is very, very hard to detect newlines of any sort with `scanf()` and friends.  If you need to detect empty lines, then use `fgets()` or equivalent to read the material, and `sscanf()` to analyze the lines after you know it isn't empty.  Any white space in a `scanf()` format string matches a sequence of zero or more white space characters; newlines, blanks, tabs are all white space.  The newline in `"\n%c"` skips white space until the next character isn't white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is safe to assume that the `matrix_read_prp_2()` function leaves the newline in the input buffer, then it would be possible to revise I/O operations in the tail of the loop along these lines:

```
    // Read anything left over to end of line
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(input)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;
    // Break on EOF or second newline
    if (c == EOF || (c = getc(input)) == EOF || c == '\n')
        break;
    // if not new line, put the char back and continue
    ungetc(c, input);
}
```

<sup>*Untested code.*</sup>

I'm not clear under what circumstances the `nasrat(mgr, op);` function call should be made; neither `mgr` nor `op` appears in the loop.

Comment: I used similar solution with slightly more verbose code that does the same thing. Thanks for answer. The `nasrat` function was used to `exit()` the program, the arguments passed to it were memory managers which were cleaned up before exiting. I removed it from the question. The reason it was called is that it is indeed safe to assume that when `matrix_read_prp_2` ends, there should be new line in the buffer, lest the input is invalid.